# How to Add a menu to the Visual Studio menu bar in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I followed this [Ms Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-menu-to-the-visual-studio-menu-bar?view=vs-2022), trying to add a test menu to the main menu bar.

But what I get is the following.

[image: Menu Adding to Extensions Menu of Visual Studio 2022]

But instead, what I want is the Test Menu on the main menu bar itself.

[image: Visual Studio Main Menu bar]

So what am I missing?

I have the sample code pushed to [my repo here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/LearnVsExt/tree/main/src/apps/900500-IssueReportAddMenuToMainMenuBar).

What am I missing?

Searched and found [this MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-menus?view=vs-2022#groups-on-the-visual-studio-menu-bar)

I tried with the IDs shown there, I paste them here.

### Groups on the Visual Studio menu bar

To add a menu to the menu bar, set one of these groups as its parent.

| Group | ID |
| --- | --- |
| File/Edit/View | IDG_VS_MM_FILEEDITVIEW |
| Refactoring | IDG_VS_MM_REFACTORING: |
| Project | IDG_VS_MM_PROJECT |
| Build | IDG_VS_MM_BUILDDEBUGRUN |
| Format/Tools | IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS |
| Window/Help/Community | IDG_VS_MM_WINDOWHELP |
| Addins | IDG_VS_MM_MACROS |
| FullScreenBar | IDG_VS_MM_FULLSCREENBAR |

But I always get the menu on the same Extensions Menu.

Is it even possible? Am I asking for too much?

If you look at [the above MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/guids-and-ids-of-visual-studio-menus?view=vs-2022#groups-on-the-visual-studio-menu-bar) and scroll a bit up, immediately above, we find the following.

> The menus and groups on the Visual Studio menu bar use the GUID `guidSHLMainMenu`. The menu bar itself has an ID of `IDM_VS_TOOL_MAINMENU`.

I tried with this id `IDM_VS_TOOL_MAINMENU` as well, going up and down the hierarchy, with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it finally.

Press F5 to debug.

[image: Debugging Vs]

This launches Experimental version of Visual Studio.

[image: Expermental Mode Visual Studio 2022]

Now Tools -> Customize

[image: Tools Customize of Visual Studio 2022]

And here we have Extensions Menu.

[image: Extensions Menu in Customize]

Uncheck the check box for Test Menu. Save and Restart.

Finally.

[image: New Menu Item in the Menu Bar of Visual Studio]